# SSH into raspberry pi that is running Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu mate 18.04 on a raspberry pi 3B+ for a robotics class and we have to ssh into the pi. I am unable to do so and when I run:
"sudp service ssh status" 
on the pi I get an error that says :
"fatal: No supported key exchange algorithm [preauth]"

Any help would be great thanks. 
Thanks

Comment: Also when I run: "ssh ubuntu@ipaddress" on my mac I get an error that says: "Connection closed by 129.161.38.210 port 22"

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [raspberrypi.se], [unix.se], or [su]. When you do, run ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output, then include the output in your question.